# SSRS SUM color base on additional parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My report looks like in picture below: each row is a location, columns are dates, qty is a SUM.

[image]

In this example QTY would be 30, I would like to color it following logic:

If all parameters are the same and equal to some value apply color.
If all parameters are not the same apply color.

**EDIT:**
param is a part of Dataset

Comment: How many parameters do you have? Are they all the exact same Data Type?

Comment: param column can have 3 values, but number can change over time. Yes they are all the same Data Type - they are 2 char strings like AA, BB, CC

Comment: So when you say parameter you're talking about a column in the Dataset and **not** a report parameter?

Comment: Yes it is a part of Dataset, sorry I should make that clear from beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an appropriately scoped `CountDistinct` here in the **Color** or **BackgroundColor** expression as required. Something like:

```
=IIf(CountDistinct(Fields!param.Value, "MyGroup") > 1, "Red", "Green")
```

Where `MyGroup` is the Scope you want to look at; you might want to change it to the Scope of your DataSet or whatever. I've just assumed group based on your data.

In this expression, the highlight will be `Red` when there is more than one distinct param in Scope, otherwise `Green`.

**Edit after comment**

Where you want to group certain param items together, you could use a **Calculated Field** to group these together in your DataSet definition, then just use this as required in your report. The Calculated Field, let's call it `paramColour`, might look like:

```
=Switch(Fields!param.Value = "AA" or Fields!param.Value = "BB", "Orange"
  , Fields!param.Value = "CC", "Green"
  , true, "Red")
```

I used a `Switch` here to make it easier to add future values.

You can then use this directly to set properties, i.e. set **BackgroundColor** to this value, or just amend the expression above:

```
=IIf(CountDistinct(Fields!paramColour.Value, "MyGroup") > 1, "Red", "Green")
```

It's nice having a Calculated Field as you can define it once for the DataSet and use it in multiple places in the report.

Comment: That is a great idea. Would you have any suggestions what should I do in case when I have to group parm values - for example AA and BB would have orange color assigned to them  ?

Comment: @witpo, I added a few thoughts.